# How to redirect to saleforce1 app detail page from apex controller

Tags: apex

I need to implement redirection. My scenario is when users clicks on any custon action(VisualForce page) in salesfroce1 app it should redirect to detail page in salesforce1app. The redirection part is handeled by controller where I am using page reference.
I got one way to redircet to salesforce1 app by giving the URl I dont want to specify URL directly.

Currently I am using like

If we want to redirect to another page or detail page of object we will use below code.

```
PageReference newocp = new PageReference('/apex/VFPage1?accId=account.Id');
PageReference newocp = new PageReference('/'+account.Id');
```

Same way I want to redirect to Salesforce1 detail page.
Currently I am using below code to redirect to detail page in salesforce1.This is working fine but the problem is every time its refresh(restart) the salesforce1 app. Please suggest me.

```
Pagereference Pageref = new Pagereference('Https://Salesfroce.com/#apps/sobjects/'+Id+'/view?=123143434');
```

Comment: Your question is difficult to read, and it's hard to understand what your problem is.  Try rewriting it to provide more context, explaining exactly what you've done so far, where it's failing, and how you'd like it to behave.

Comment: HI Bod, modified the question I think it is clear now.If u want something please comment, so that i will add my code.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Managing Navigation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1/Content/vf_dev_best_practices_navigation.htm) and [Creating Visualforce Pages That Work in Mobile and Desktop](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1/Content/vf_dev_best_practices_pages_multipurpose.htm). I believe navigating by `PageReference` is not supported in `Salesforce1`. Instead, you should manage it in Javascript:

```
// Go back to the Account detail page
if( (typeof sforce != 'undefined') && (sforce != null) ) {
    // Salesforce1 navigation
    sforce.one.navigateToSObject(aId);
}
else {
    // Set the window's URL using a Visualforce expression
    window.location.href = 
        '{!URLFOR($Action.Account.View, account.Id)}';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage **sforce.one** Object to perform navigation in Salesforce 1.

I had one such requirement where I needed to redirect users to mobile / site based on mouse click. See this:

```
$("#SomeIdofComponent").click(function(){
var url = '/apex/YourVFpage?id='+ "{!Your_sObject_Id}";
gotourl('/apex/YourVFpage?id='+ "{!Your_sObject_Id}"); 
}
```

This is the function that I created as utility function:

```
function gotourl(url){
if(typeof sforce == 'undefined') 
window.location.href = url
else
sforce.one.navigateToURL(url);
}
```

Just remember to create your Visualforce page that works well in both the Salesforce1 app and the full Salesforce site.

Here is the [Link](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1/Content/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm) for your reference.