# ApexPages.StandardController(record).edit() does not show updates in edit page

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce1-app, mobile

So I have a controller where values are updated.  However, when I pass the page reference to immediately open the edit page (in salesforce 1) the page passed does not contain any of the updates.

Is there anything I have to do to open the edit page with the changes made on save?  This used to work, I'm not sure why it doesn't anymore (I'm in winter 17 38.0 sandbox, perhaps that is something).

ApexPages.StandardController(object).edit() does not pass the new values to the edit form

PageReference('/' + object.id) shows the detail page which contains the new values (in this case check_out_time).

**UPDATE:** One really weird thing is if I create the record on the desktop and then save it (using this method) it updates perfectly.

**WORKFLOW** user creates record from mobile, edit screen opens, user clicks save, user opens another form which is a list view, clicks save and the below code runs.  It could be that the edit screen is caching the old values.  However, I turned off my phone and turned it back on and that wasn't the case.

**UPDATE 2** so I suspected it cached the edit form.  So I created the record, uninstalled the app to clear the cache of that edit form, then checked out (using the code below) and it worked.

```
public PageReference save(){
        Activity__c a = [select id, Check_out_time__c from Activity__c where id =: paramId limit 1];

        system.debug('id is ' + string.valueOf(paramId));
        if (a != null)
        {           
            system.debug('records found');
            system.debug('time is: ' + string.valueOf(a.Check_out_time__c));
            datetime now = datetime.now();
            a.Check_out_time__c = now;
            a.Original_Check_out__c = now;
            system.debug('new time is: ' + string.valueOf(a.Check_out_time__c));
            //a.Checked_out_from_mobile__c = true;
            update a;                

            //does not work all of the sudden
            //PageReference page = new ApexPages.StandardController(a).edit();

            //Works
            PageReference page = new PageReference('/'+ a.id);
            page.setRedirect(true);         
            return page;            
        }
        return null;

    }
```

**This is what I sent to salesforce premier support (we are unlimited customers):**
I have an app that creates a record via button click and opens the edit form. The user saves the record and later opens a different form to "close (runs a trigger on)" that record via a button click and re-opens the edit form. However, when I open the edit form in SF1 the second time, it contains all of the information from the first time it was opened. Therefore, when I click save it enacts collision detection and says the record cannot save. If I modify the code and go to the view page, everything is fine; if I create the record in the desktop mode and then "close" it on mobile mode it also works okay. 
So I started thinking that SF1 was caching the edit pages. So I created a record via mobile which opened the edit page and I saved, I force quit the app (iOS double home button tap), re-opened that app, same issue it disregarded the trigger actions and opened the "old data". I took it a step further, I created a record, saved from edit, restarted my phone, same behavior (collision detection/old date); finally I created the record, saved, uninstalled the app, re-installed the app, I was able to "close" the record. I tried it a second time and it still worked.

Is there a known issue with SF1 caching the edit page? Is there a way I can clear that cache?

This was not happening a few weeks ago*

Comment: yes, I can see it in the log.

Comment: mainly because it says the record has changed between opening the edit page and pressing save.

Comment: In the controller the Check_out_time is updated to now().  However, when the edit page opens (in salesforce1) check_out_time is null.   If I check the database at that moment, the check_out_time is not null.  So the UI thinks it's null, the database has it updated and when I click save I get a "collision detection" error.  It appears that the UI is opening before data is committed to the database.

Comment: how would I go about adding "FOR UPDATE"?

Comment: I tried the FOR UPDATE.  I ended up with the same error "this record was modified by <USER> during the edit session.  Make a note of the data you enetered then reload the record and enter your updates again"

Comment: I think the problem is the redirection using the PageReference is Salesforce1, checkout http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/75971/how-to-redirect-to-saleforce1-app-detail-page-from-apex-controller OR http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/97019/custom-action-salesforce1-redirect-to-source-record

Comment: I'm successful in navigating by javascript on the insert but not the update.  I'll keep playing around with the javascript

Comment: I opened up a case with premier support.  It looks like it's a caching issue within SF1.  Perhaps they can install an old version and see if that's the issue.  I don't think I can downgrade on my iPhone.